# How to Download and save image in external storage from webview?

Tags: android, webview, bitmap, android-webview, android-download-manager

1. I want to download images in sdCard from webview by long pressing on the images.
2. I want to share image by long pressing on the image without storing the image in sdCard just like chrome.
   I can download images but they are not saving in sdCard.
   I almost searched on entire web but didn't get any solution.

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   WebView webView;
   String HTTP_URL = "https://www.google.com" ;
   private long downloadID ;
   Bitmap bitmap;
   Tag TAG;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
   webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
   webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

   registerForContextMenu(webView);
   webView.loadUrl(HTTP_URL);

   @Override
   public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu contextMenu, View view,
   ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo contextMenuInfo){
   super.onCreateContextMenu(contextMenu, view, contextMenuInfo);

   final WebView.HitTestResult webViewHitTestResult = webView.getHitTestResult();

   if (webViewHitTestResult.getType() == WebView.HitTestResult.IMAGE_TYPE ||
   webViewHitTestResult.getType() == WebView.HitTestResult.SRC_IMAGE_ANCHOR_TYPE) {

   contextMenu.setHeaderTitle("Select option");


   contextMenu.add(0, 1, 0, "Download Image")
   .setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {

   String DownloadImageURL = webViewHitTestResult.getExtra();

   if(URLUtil.isValidUrl(DownloadImageURL)){

   DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(DownloadImageURL));
   request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();


   request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
   DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
   downloadID = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
   String publicDirPath = ExternalStorageUtil.getPublicExternalStorageBaseDir("/");
   File newFile = new File(publicDirPath, "download");
   newFile.mkdirs();

   File newFile1 = new File(newFile, "image.png");
   OutputStream os;

   try {
   os = new FileOutputStream(newFile1);
   bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os);
   os.flush();
   os.close();
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   }

   } return false;
   }



   //set Download Listener

   webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

   public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
   String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
   long contentLength) {

   DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
   request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();

   request.setNotificationVisibility(
   DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

   request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("timestop", "Tillem");

   DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(
   DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

   dm.enqueue(request);


   }});
   }}
   ```

Comment: You should format your question and not using the BOLD lettertype unnecessary.

Comment: Done. Sorry for that, it is my first question on stackoverflow.

Comment: manifest file manifest.xml
        `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`
        `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> `
        `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> `
        `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>`